# Border is displaying when image-link is clicked

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page and when an image is clicked in that moment a border is displayed around the image, the image at the same time is a link, why is this happening? it just happens when the image is clicked.
This is my code:

```
<div id="hammer">
      <a asp-action="myaction" asp-controller="mycontroller" class="col-xs-6"> <img src="~/images/online_keyboard_news.jpg" class="highlight" width="100%" height="auto" /> firstimage</a> 
        <a asp-action="myaction2" asp-controller="mycontroller2" class="col-xs-6"> <img src="~/images/document-428336_960_720.jpg" class="highlight" width="100%" height="auto" /> secondimage</a>
        </div>
        <br />
```

and this is the css class I'm using:

```
#hammer {
        font-size: 18pt;       
        margin: 15px 0 0 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

This is what is happening just when an image is clicked:
[image]

Comment: what browser are you using?. because sometimes it depends on the browser. try it in other browsers

Comment: @ooo-Ghost-ooo you are right, this is happening just with Internet Explorer, I've tried with Google Chrome now and the border is not displayed, any idea of how can I avoid it in Internet Explorer, my Internet Explorer version is 11

Comment: Sorry dude. i don't know how to fix it yet, i just have encountered it when where having an exercises at school.

Comment: @ooo-Ghost-ooo it works with outline:none as said in the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `outline:none;` for all `a` and `img` elements

```
#hammer a, #hammer a img{
  outline:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to set the [outline css property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) to none:

```
#hammer a, #hammer img {
  outline: none;
}
```

Let me now if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css

```
#hammer > a {
   outline: 0;
}
```